# Calling a setter on an array of objects

Tags: java, oop

I'm trying to code a console-based farm simulator game. My classes are:

**Board.java**

```
public class Board {
    Spot[][] board = new Spot[50][50];
    Values free = new Values(1000,'_');
    Plant plant = new Plant(10,'@');

    public Board() {
        for(int i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < MAX_SIZE; ++j)
                board[i][j] = new Spot(plant);
    }
}
```

**Spot.java**

```
public class Spot {

    Values values;

    public Values getValue() {
        return values;
    }

    public void setValue(Values values) {
        this.values = values;
    }
}
```

**Values.java**

```
public class Values{
    private int price,time;
    private char sign;

    public Values(int price, char sign){
        setPrice(price);
        setSign(sign);
    }
    // All the setters and getters...
}
```

**Plant.java**

```
public class Plant extends Values {
    private boolean onfire;

    public Plant(int price, char sign)
        super(price,sign);
        setOnFire(false);
    }    
    // Setter and getter for onfire...
}
```

The problem: when calling `(Plant)(board[0][0].getValue()).setOnFire(true)`, it applies for each element of `board` that has an `instanceof Plant`.

Comment: `board[i][j] = new Spot(pant);`

There is no such constructor in Spot class

Comment: It's because you pass the same Plant instance to every Spot at: `new Spot(plant);`. If you want Plant / Values to have separate state you should make separate objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why all of the plants were set on fire when you've only called on one is that you've assigned all of the spots the exact same plant in the board initialisation hence there's ever only 1 plant to begin with.
Try `board[i][j] = new Spot(`**`new Plant(...)`**`);` so that each spot gets its own default plant that are independent of one another.
Although this wasn't part of the question: **you will run into the same problem once you start calling `setValue()` on any of the `free` values for the same reason!**

It looks as though you were trying to create a default `Value` and `Plant` at the beginning of your board class. There are multiple ways around this in addition to the above such as:

1. Explicitly listing out the default values that you can then feed into their respective constructors:
   `private char valueSign = '_';`
   `private char plantSign = '@';`, etc.
   Then you can do `board[i][j] = new Spot(new Plant(plantValue, plantSign));`.
2. Create a default constructor in the spot classes.
3. Leave your code as they are and just clone the default plant:
   `board[i][j] = new Spot(plant.clone())`.

All of these should fix the problem you are having. Whichever method you choose depends on how you want to organise your game and where the data should live. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

"it applies for each element" - this means that you all of those references point to a single object in memory.

Look at your loop in `Board` class. You create multiple `Spot`s - you call its constructor in the loop. But your `Plant` is declared only once and passed as an argument in `Spot`'s constructor. This means that all `Spot`s share a single `Plant`.

Check it out by trying `board[0][0].getValue() == board[0][1].getValue()`. I guess the result is `true`, but what you want is `false`.

It is enough to move your `Plant` declaration to inside the loop (you might need to do the same with `Values`).